# Multiple Filter conditions in MPP thru Project Interop

Tags: c#, ms-project

I am using MS Project interop to automate reading MPP. Implementing single column filter is working however just wondering, how do I implement multiple column filter with or/add condition? I am using below code to filter single column which works:

```
public string Load(string fileName)
{
            MSProject.ApplicationClass app = null;
            try
            {
                app = new MSProject.ApplicationClass();
                app.Visible = false;

                if (app.FileOpen(fileName, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, MSProject.PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadOnly, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
                {
                    app.FilterEdit("My New Filter", true, true, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "Resource Names", Type.Missing, "equals", "ResourceNameHere1", Type.Missing, true, true);
                    //app.FilterApply("Using Resource...", "false", "ResourceNameHere1");
                    app.SelectAll();
                    MSProject.Tasks tsk = (MSProject.Tasks)app.ActiveSelection.Tasks;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Q:

How to add one more resource name in condition? Like to pull ResourceName1 along with ResourceName2 with and/or condition or add condition to filter by % complete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Since you want summary tasks, creating a filter is a good option. Here's how to create a filter with 3 criteria--2 resources and % Complete:

```
app.FilterEdit("My New Filter", true, true, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "Resource Names", Type.Missing, "contains", "ResourceNameHere1", Type.Missing, true, true);
app.FilterEdit("My New Filter", true, false, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "Resource Names", "contains", "ResourceNameHere1", "Or", true, true);
app.FilterEdit("My New Filter", true, false, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "% Complete", "is less than", "100", "And", true, true);
```

**Previous answer**

If the goal is to loop through a set of tasks that meet certain criteria, there is no need to bother with creating a filter, setting it, then selecting all visible tasks. Here's pseudo code to get you started:

```
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If (t.ResourceNames Like "*Name1*" Or t.ResourceNames Like "*Name2*") And t.PercentComplete < 100 Then
        ' do something
    End If
Next t
```

FYI: To get a reference to a task's summary task, use the OutlineParent property.

Comment: I will lose Summary tasks and their hierarchy with this approach because summary tasks won't have resource name. Won't I?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess, you'l solution should work. I realized my mistake as well when I tried adding multiple filters.